# insert user id in another table during registration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I have a registration form that captures email and password. Once the form is submitted it will add an AUTO_INCREMENT userid, email, and password into my users table. During this same submit process I would like to add the ID that was created in my users table to a users_preferences table.

Here is what I currently have:

```
require("config.php");
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user fills out fields 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { die("Please enter a username."); }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); }  
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { die("Please enter a password."); } 

    // Check if the username is already taken
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); } 


    // Add row to database         
    $query = "             
        BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt
        ) ;
        INSERT INTO user_preferences (
            user_id
        ) VALUES (
            $user_id
        );
        COMMIT;
    "; 
     $user_id = mysql_insert_id();

    // Security measures
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); } 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt 
    ); 
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}
```

The registration of the user will go through and add the data to the database, but no data is added to the user_preferences table. How do I get this to add the last user id to the second table?

Comment: Why can't you use a separate query?

Comment: The reason it's not working is that you can't execute multiple queries like that. Split it into multiple queries. I'm referring to the query beginning with comment `// Add row to database  `. Also, you're mixing PDO and `mysql_` for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that you are trying to put the value of `$user_id` into the query, yet it would only receive a value in the next command row (although you're not actually running the first query, you're just trying to fetch the last inserted id).

You should first run the `INSERT INTO users...` query, then retrieve the last inserted id, then run the second query (`INSERT INTO user_preferences...`).

Also assuming you're using PDO, last inserted id should be `$db->lastInsertId()` in your context.

** Update

Alright, without changing your code, just mostly refactoring it a tad bit, you should try something like this:

```
function checkDataValidity(){
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        throw new Exception("Please enter a username."); 
    }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
        throw new Exception("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
    }  
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){ 
        throw new Exception("Please enter a password."); 
    } 
}

function doesUserExist($dbHandler){
    $query  = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username;"; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    $stmt   = $dbHandler->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        throw new Exception('This email address is already registered');
    }
}

function insertNewUser($dbHandler){
    try{
        $salt     = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt 
        ); 

        $dbHandler->beginTransaction();
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) VALUES ( :username,  :password, :salt );";
        $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

        $newUserId = $dbHandler->lastInsertId();
        $dbHandler->commit();

    }catch(Exception $dbException){
        $dbHandler->rollback();
        $newUserId = NULL;
    }

    return $newUserId;
}

function insertUserPreference($dbHandler, $userId){
    $query_params = array( 
        ':user_id' => $userId
    );
    try{
        $dbHandler->beginTransaction();
        $query = "INSERT INTO user_preferences ( user_id ) VALUES ( :user_id );"; 
        $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

        $dbHandler->commit();

    }catch(Exception $dbException){
        $dbHandler->rollback();
    }
}

require("config.php");
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    try{
        checkDataValidity();
        doesUserExist($db);
        $newUserId = insertNewUser($db);

        if (!is_null($newUserId)){
            insertUserPreference($db, $newUserId);
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Error inserting user');
        }

        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'The following error occured: <br/>'.$e->getMessage();
    }   
}
```

Don't let the changes baffle you - I've only rearranged your code to be more easily readable. The above solves the original problem by moving the "user insert" into one function where we return the new ID if the insert was successful, otherwise null value, and we also move the second half of the query into its own function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a new to php and mysql/PDO and a little lost at how I should write this. Can you give an example?

Comment: I added this piece of code: `$sql = "
   INSERT INTO user_preferences (
    user_id
   ) VALUES (
    :user_id
   );
   ";
      
         $query_params = array(
          ':user_id' => $db->lastInsertId(), 
         );
         try {
          $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
         }
  catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } ` but I receive this error: Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.user_preferences' doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I am receiving this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /homepages/28/d531081792/htdocs/home/metro-home/admin-page/submit.php on line 40` Also, did you remove PDO?

Comment: Could this have somethingg to do with my config.php file? It shows PDO in the code. If you need to see the config file let me know and I will update my first post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in my time zone it was already getting a bit late . The problem arose because I accidentally didn't change your `$db` variable to `$dbHandler` (in the `insertNewUser` and `insertUserPreference` functions). I'll update my answer right away.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't give me any errors and it added the user to the users table, but did not add anything to the user_preferences table.

Comment: Well, not quite sure about that - you'll have to get your hands a bit dirty with some debugging there. Try adding this line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` just after `require("config.php");` This is a useful setting for development stage if you wish to see all levels of warnings and errors. In case there is some semantic, or SQL problem here in the `insertUserPreference` function, you should add into the catch block of the function code the following `echo $dbException->getMessage();`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the 2 pieces of code you mentioned above and received this error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db538127315.user_preferences' doesn't exist
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/28/d531081792/htdocs/home/metro-home/admin-page/submit.php:68) in /homepages/28/d531081792/htdocs/home/metro-home/admin-page/submit.php on line 87
Redirecting to index.php` Any suggestions?

Comment: I am a HUGE idiot. When I created my user_preferences table I accidentally include a space before user lol. It's all working great now thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having an issue with another problem getting data from database and updating html based on that data. Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: I see you've already made a question for it, and got an almost complete solution over there, so if I can assist in anything, I'll do it over there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look. I just update my post with the second part that I need to do.

Comment: is it possible for you to take a look at this question I post? [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774536/insert-user-id-in-2-tables-during-registration) it is basically the same insert function, but I cannot get it to work.